# Using Python How to fetch data from AWS Parameter store in CI Jenkin server (which runs my tests nightly)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, parameters

I have spent a lot of time searching the web for this answer.

I know how to get my QA env aws_access_key_id & aws_secret_access_key while running my code locally on my PC which are stored in  my C:\Users[name].aws config file

```
[profile qa]
aws_access_key_id = ABC
aws_secret_access_key = XYZ

[profile crossaccount]
role_arn=arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:12345678:parameter/A/B/secrets/C
source_profile=qa
```

Like this python code and I actually see the correct values.

```
    import boto3
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='qa')
    s3client = session.client('s3')
    credentials = session.get_credentials()
    accessKey = credentials.access_key
    secretKey = credentials.secret_key
    print("accessKey= " + str(accessKey) + " secretKey="+ secretKey)
```

A) How do I get these when my code is running on CI do I pass the "aws_access_key_id" and "aws_secret_access_key" as arguments to the code?

B) How exactly do I assume a role and get the parameters from AWS System manager parameter store 
Given I know

```
secretsExternalId: 'DEF',
secretsRoleArn: 'arn:aws:ssm:us-east-1:12345678:parameter/A/B/secrets/C',
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by CI? An AWS CodeBuild server? A Jenkins server in your office? Something else?

Comment: Yes I just updated the summary thx Jenkin server (which runs my tests nightly)

Comment: Is the Jenkins server running on AWS?

Comment: yes it is both my unittest as well as the CI Jenkins are on AWS

Answer (score 1):

Install boto3 and botocore on the CI server.
As you mentioned the CI(Jenkins) is also running on AWS. You can attach a role to the CI server(EC2) which provides SSM read permission.

Below is the sample permission for the role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ssm:Describe*",
                "ssm:Get*",
                "ssm:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And from your python code, you can simply call the ssm to get the parameter values.

```
$ export parameter_value1="/path/to/ssm/parameter_1"
$ export parameter_value2="/path/to/ssm/parameter_2"
```

```
import os
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(region_name='eu-west-1')
ssm = session.client('ssm')

MYSQL_HOSTNAME = os.environ.get('parameter_value1')
MYSQL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('parameter_value2')

hostname = ssm.get_parameter(Name=parameter_value1, WithDecryption=True)
username = ssm.get_parameter(Name=parameter_value2, WithDecryption=True)

print("Param1: {}".format(hostname['Parameter']['Value']))
print("Param2: {}".format(username['Parameter']['Value']))
```